# How do I exit my program on OK button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exit

I have a button called exit that calls up a msg box asking for confirmation with vbOKCancel. How do I get the program to exit when the user presses OK?

This is what I have currently:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditGoals.Click
    GoalCountdown.Text = "Congratulations"
End Sub

Private Sub ExitProgram_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitProgram.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Exit Sub



        End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a .NET Windows Forms application:

```
Private Sub ExitProgram_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitProgram.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to avoid brutally exiting your application but `End` will do the trick.

By that I mean that you could call `End` in the handler of your button's click event but a better approach would be to try to gracefully close whatever application you are using vbscript with (ie. If it's VB Script running inside of an Access database app then you would want to invoke the Close method on the main Access application object).

Answer (score 0):

`Application.exit` is indeed correct, but you can also use `e.cancel = false` to close a form if you are closing it with the red X.

```
Private Sub Form1Close(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim Result As DialogResult
    If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        e.Cancel = False
    ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

--

```
Private Sub Form1Close(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim Result As DialogResult
    If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Application.Exit()
    ElseIf Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```